# Seguridad al ingresar credenciales MySql en php

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad

¡Hola! Por lo que tengo entendido todos pueden ver el código de una pagina, ¿si yo quiero hacer una conexión con una base de datos, al ingresar el host, usuario, contraseña se mostraria en el codigo de mi pagina (.php) y todos podrian verlo? Es un sistema que no puede tener una falla asi de grande y necesito su ayuda. Gracias!

Comment: el c´digo de servidor PHP, se procesa en el server entonces tus usuarios no verían esos datos solo verían el resultado de la conexión

Comment: ya tienes un ejemplo o quieres conocer como hacerlo de manera segura la conexión?

Comment: Me refiero a que si pueden ver las credenciales de mysql, no lo que envie

Comment: no tienen por que verse la conexión se hace a nivel de servidor y el usuario solo ve resultados de frontend o lo que por consultas le proceses de la base de datos

Comment: Ok gracias! Saludos!

Comment: Bueno depende. Por ejemplo si usas PDO y lo tienes mal configurado, las credenciales se podrían mostrar en el log de errores... lo cual es gravísimo. Igualmente, si usas la extensión obsoleta `mysql_*` y hay algún fallo, las credenciales también se mostrarán en el log de errores. Como consejo te recomiendo que uses contraseñas largas, el máximo permitido... no recuerdo ahora si es de 30 o 50 caracteres. Yo tengo una contraseña larga y precisamente hace poco en una página alojada en Wordpress configuré mi hosting a PHP y WP me estaba dando errores...

Comment: ... la consecuencia de eso es que el mensaje de error incluía la contraseña de mi bd sólo que como era larga, no se veía completa, gracias a Dios, pero se veían bastante caracteres de ella, no recuerdo si 15 o 20 caracteres, pero como mi contraseña tiene 30, no se veía completa. El problema es que WP usa todavía (no sé por qué), la API `mysql_*` la cual no funciona en PHP 7. Entonces daba un error mostrando las credenciales.

Comment: le sugiero que utilice los framework, no solo te ahorra tiempo al hace un proyecto sino que cuenta con la parte de la seguridad